# android support SortedList will get duplicate entries after calling addAll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-support-library

Using android support library `com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1`.

After calling SortedList.addAll() with a bunch of items, the list may end up with duplicates. In particular, this will happen if the newly added items exist but are changed in a way that affects their sorting.

Code example:

```
    class TestItem {
        final int id;
        final String name;

        TestItem(int id, String name) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

    SortedList<TestItem> list = new SortedList<TestItem>(TestItem.class, new Callback<TestItem>
            () {
        @Override
        public int compare(TestItem o1, TestItem o2) {
            if (areItemsTheSame(o1, o2)) {
                return 0;
            } else {
                return o1.name.compareTo(o2.name);
            }
        }

        // onXxx methods left out for readability

        @Override
        public boolean areContentsTheSame(TestItem oldItem, TestItem newItem) {
            return oldItem.name.equals(newItem.name);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean areItemsTheSame(TestItem item1, TestItem item2) {
            return item1.id == item2.id;
        }
    });

    list.add(new TestItem(1, "Bravo"));
    list.add(new TestItem(2, "Charlie"));
    list.addAll(new TestItem(2, "Alpha"));
```

After running this code, the list will contain `[Alpha, Bravo, Charlie]` instead of, as expected, `[Alpha, Bravo]` (`Alpha` should have *replaced* `Charlie`).

What is the best way around this?

Answer (score 0):

I have submitted this as a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=201618) with Google.

Working workaround for a set of new items `newItems`

```
list.beginBatchedUpdates();
for (TestItem item : newItems) {
    list.add(item);
}
list.endBatchedUpdates();
```